# Pencil Sketches in an activity

Tags: android

Please help me out if there's a way to do this.

I have a ImageView. Loaded with a Default image. In my app, I want this to be circled, say with an pencil sketch, like it was circled using a pencil, and an arrow leading from it. Is there a way to put this up around the image view, in the layout? Please help me.

Comment: You haven't asked a question. You've said what you want but SO is not a place where people do your work for you, it's a place where you ask a well defined (not vague) question and people try to answer you. Generally you describe what you've already tried and what you didn't like about the outcome. http://stackoverflow.com/faq is your best SO friend for the moment.

Comment: I am extremely sry. Am new to this one. I will reframe my question.

Comment: Please refer the edit. I typed that in that in an hurry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this (there may be others) is to replace the ImageView with a RelativeLayout. Place your current ImageView in that RelativeLayout, and also place a 2nd ImageView in it such that both overlap the same place. The 2nd ImageView will contain the image of your pencil/arrow and will otherwise be transparent.

Depending on the exact appearance you're looking for, you may find you need the RelativeLayout to take up more screen space than your primary image, so that your overlay can go beyond that image.

Comment: thanks. I got the picture now. Will try this :).